# Why is Geforce Now running slow on Google Chrome ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, games, chromebook

guys, I have ubuntu os on a Chromebook but it was originally chrome os and when it was I was able to get GeForce now on google chrome and play Fortnite smoothly but now that I have google chrome on ubuntu os it's not so smooth do you guys know why. (FYI) I have a Chromebook 15 cb3-532 and ubuntu 20.04, I don't plan on streaming so I have no other software running.

Comment: How have you installed Ubuntu on the Chromebook? Many people claim they have, which is usually a misconception as they are unable to configure the necessary firmware/bootloader and kernel. Ubuntu is [not a supported platform for Geforce Now](https://www.nvidia.com/de-de/geforce-now/download/). What ever you did to get past the checks—like user agent spoofing—doesn't make your setup a supported platform and you cannot expect volunteers to offer you world class support with so little information. You are using products in an unsupported and poorly documented way. I vote to close your question.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I hope you get this I downloaded chrome from firefox it usually does not work with firefox, brave, or any other browser except chrome and edge so i just download chrome